# No volley response when I access activity again

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a main page where I fetch a bunch of items from server using Volley and then I load them up on screen. If I click on an item, it should take me to the item page displaying its details which I'm fetching from server again using Volley. The latter (getting details for a single item on the single item page) works only once.

So for example if I access item page the first time, Volley gets me the response, so I can load data to screen. But if I press back or just go back to main page and select another item, Volley fails to give any responses, so the item page is empty. How do I make Volley send request and get response every time I access the Item page? or at least tell me why is it working only the first time?

My singleton class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

How I make request and deal with response on Item Page, my ReadDataFromDB() method...

```
private void ReadDataFromDB() {
        JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            int success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {

                            //parse JSON
                                JSONObject productJSONObject = response.getJSONObject(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                                 product = new ProdItem (productJSONObject.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_PICTURE), productJSONObject.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_TITLE), productJSONObject.getString(TAG_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION),
                                        productJSONObject.getString(TAG_PRODUCTS_DATETIME), productJSONObject.getDouble(TAG_PRODUCTS_RATING),
                                        productJSONObject.getDouble(TAG_PRODUCTS_PRICE), productJSONObject.getInt(TAG_PRODUCT_ID), productJSONObject.getInt(TAG_CAT_ID), productJSONObject.getInt(TAG_PRODUCTS_VIEWS),
                                        productJSONObject.getInt(TAG_PRODUCTS_SHOPID), productJSONObject.getInt(TAG_PRODUCT_POINTS), 1, productJSONObject.getString(TAG_PRODUCTS_SHOPNAME));

                            } // if ends

                            //update UI
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    adTitleLBL.setText(product.getProdTitle());
                                    shopNameLBL.setText(product.getShopName());
                                    prodDescriptionLBL.setText(product.getProdDescription());
                                    shopIDLBL.setText(String.valueOf(product.getProdShopID()));
                                    catIDLBL.setText(String.valueOf(product.getMasterCatID()));
                                    prdoIDLBL.setText(String.valueOf(product.getProdID()));

                                    adRating.setRating((float) product.getProdRating());
                                    loadAdImage(product.getProdImage());
                                }
                            });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server is terrible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        //add request to queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jreq);

    }
```

I checked for other questions here, but they're not what I'm looking for. I'm probably using Volley wrong, just need to know what I'm missing or what is it.

Comment: onResponse runs on ui thread

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but synchronizing your application's `getInstance()` is pointless.  You may want to synchronize `getReqQueue()` depending on whether it'll be called outside the main thread.  (I don't know if Volley request queues are even thread safe.)

Comment: @KaranMer Oh alright.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Point noted. See, this is why I'm using Vollley because I've read around that it does quite well with threads, so I need to check that out. But first, if I could just figure this issue out.